# "Allowed to navigate" algorithm in whatwg

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'am trying to realize when browser will throw an error due with **[allowed to navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#allowed-to-navigate)** algorithm. Unfortunately, I don't understand its complex conditions.

> A [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context) A is **allowed to navigate** a second [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context) B if the following algorithm returns true:
>
> 1. If A is not the same [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browsing-context) as B, and A is not one of the
>    [ancestor browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#ancestor-browsing-context) of B, and B is not a [top-level browsing
>    context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context), and A's [active document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-document)'s [active sandboxing flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#active-sandboxing-flag-set) has
>    its [sandboxed navigation browsing context flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-navigation-browsing-context-flag), then return
>    false.
> 2. Otherwise, if B is a [top-level browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context), and is one of the [ancestor browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#ancestor-browsing-context) of A, then:
>
>    1. If A's [active window](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-window) has [transient activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#transient-activation) and A's [active document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-document)'s [active sandboxing
>       flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#active-sandboxing-flag-set) has its [sandboxed top-level navigation with user activation
>       browsing context flag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-top-level-navigation-with-user-activation-browsing-context-flag) set, then return false.
>    2. Otherwise, if A's
>       [active window](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-window) does not have [transient activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#transient-activation) and A's [active
>       document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#active-document)'s [active sandboxing flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#active-sandboxing-flag-set) has its [sandboxed top-level
>       navigation without user activation browsing context flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-top-level-navigation-without-user-activation-browsing-context-flag), then
>       return false.
> 3. Otherwise, if B is a [top-level browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context), and is neither A
>    nor one of the [ancestor browsing contexts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#ancestor-browsing-context) of A, and A's Document's
>    [active sandboxing flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#active-sandboxing-flag-set) has its [sandboxed navigation browsing
>    context flag set](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-navigation-browsing-context-flag), and A is not the [one permitted sandboxed navigator](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#one-permitted-sandboxed-navigator)
>    of B, then return false.
> 4. Return true.

If anybody knows how to present and show every condition with understanable language, I would be glad. Also if it possible - could you express this with js code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is the concept of a browsing context. A tab, window, frame or iframe that presents a document to the user is a browsing context.

When a user opens a tab in their browser and accesses a URL from your origin through the address bar, this creates a **top-level** browsing context.

If your document uses framesets or iframes these each create a **child** browsing context whose **parent** is the **top-level** context previously mentioned. The parent can be accessed through means such as [`iframe.contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) or [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).

Each **child** can also be a **parent** to it's own child contexts. The **top-level** context of every descendant will be the original tab that was opened and can be accessed through [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top).

**Sandboxing** is automatically applied to a **top level** context. Only descendants of this context can interact with it. Sandboxing can also be applied to descendant contexts through a [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Siblings or ancestors cannot access a sandboxed context. If a descendant context belongs to a different origin than it's parent, an exception must be made to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) to allow access between them.

If your document opens a new tab or window, this creates a new **top-level** context with a single exception to it's sandbox. The opener context becomes the **one permitted sandboxed navigator**. Normally two top-level contexts cannot interact with each other, but in this case the opener can control new context that it created. The opened context can also
access the one that created it through [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener).

In addition to these restricitions. Sandboxing can also be applied to a context if it has been opened programatically and not interacted with. This is known as **transient activation**.

So, with all of that in mind. The **Allowed to Navigate** algorithm essentially boils down to this sequence :

#### If :

- A and B are not part of the same frameset, and
- B is not a descendant of A, and
- B is a not top-level context, and
- A is sandboxed, then
- Navigation is not allowed

#### Else, if :

- B is a top-level context, and
- A is descended from B , and
- A has been not interacted with, or
- Access to A is denied by CSP, then
- Navigation is not allowed

#### Else, if :

- B is a top-level context, and
- B is not A, and
- A is not descended from B, and
- A is sandboxed, and
- A did not open B, then
- Navigation is not allowed

#### Else :

- Navigation is allowed

Comment: Wow, I wasn't waiting answer at all. But it's very very good answer even perfect for placing it to whatwg spec as non-normative part. Introducing part is exellent. But when you were describing conditions I noticed errors (correct me if I am not right). And there they are: `B is a top-level context, and` instead of `B is not a top-level context, and`; `B was opened by A, and` instead of `A was opened by B, and`; What do you think? And could you tell more about **one permitted sandboxed navigator**, what does it mean?

Comment: You are right, I definitely had those conditions listed wrong. Well spotted. I've corrected the errors and also added some extra notes about the sandbox exception as you requested.

Comment: I am so liking your answer ;( Do you have blog or something about this? I would read, especially read how browsers work with explanation by algorithms from specification. It's so interesting and exciting

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you found my answer helpful. I did recently start writing articles on [dev.to](https://dev.to/besworks). I don't have much content there yet but I will be adding more. I also have posted many other informative answers here if you look through [my history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036546/besworks?tab=answers&sort=activity).